# Can't open multiple tabs in Komodo Edit/IDE 7.0.2

Tags: linux, exception, tabs, ubuntu-11.10, komodo

I cannot open more than one file in Komodo Edit/IDE 7.0.2. I have removed the /.komodoedit folder to resolve this problem at startup. It opens the first document, but I see this warning in the log:

```
[2012-03-29 17:33:36,549] [WARNING] koLanguageServiceBase.indenting: Found non-positive guess of 0 (min 1)
[2012-03-29 17:33:36,550] [WARNING] koLanguageServiceBase.indenting: Found non-positive guess of 0 (min 1)
[2012-03-29 17:33:36,550] [WARNING] koLanguageServiceBase.indenting: Found non-positive guess of 0 (min 1)
```

For the second file, it will not open the file and throws this exception:

```
ERROR:xpcom:Unhandled exception calling 'int8 note_loc(in nsISomething, in boolean, in nsISomething, out retval nsISomething);'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/xpcom/server/policy.py", line 310, in _CallMethod_
    return 0, func(*params)
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/components/koHistory.py", line 119, in note_loc
    recent_back_visits = self.get_session(loc.session_name).recent_back_visits
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 1249, in get_session
    self.sessions[session_name] = HistorySession(session_name, self.db)
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 679, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 716, in load
    self._load_recent_history_cache(top_loc_id, num_forward_visits, cu=cu)
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 740, in _load_recent_history_cache
    loc = self.db.visit_from_id(id, session_name=self.session_name, cu=cu)
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 487, in visit_from_id
    is_obsolete=row[11]
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/python/lib/python2.6/contextlib.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 233, in connect
    yield cu
  File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 472, in visit_from_id
    uri_id = int(row[1])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
[2012-03-29 17:35:13,927] [ERROR] root: 
-- EXCEPTION START --
+ QueryInterface (function) 3 lines
+ message (string) 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType''
+ result (number) 2147500037
+ name (string) 'visit_from_id'
+ filename (string) '/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py'
+ lineNumber (number) 472
+ columnNumber (number) 0
+ location (object) File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 472, in visit_from_id
| + QueryInterface (function) 3 lines
| + language (number) 0
| + languageName (string) 'Python'
| + filename (string) '/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py'
| + name (string) 'visit_from_id'
| + lineNumber (number) 472
| + sourceLine (string) 'uri_id = int(row[1])'
| + caller (object) File "/home/ali/Programlar/Komodo-Edit-7/lib/mozilla/python/komodo/editorhistory.py", line 233, in connect
| *
+ inner (object) null
| *
+ data (object) null
| *
*
-- EXCEPTION END --
```

My OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Do you have complete C++ support on your machine? One [known issue](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/releases/ide.html) in Komodo is:

> Komodo may not start up correctly on some Linux systems if C++ compatibility libraries have not been installed. On Fedora and Red Hat systems, install the "compat-libstdc++" package. On SuSE, install the "compat" package. On Gentoo, as root, run emerge lib-compat. This is not thought to be a problem on Debian systems.